# using google places api like airbnb

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

hi i'd like to make an input that can search for posts in which has address information.

i am using google places autocomplete api and they provide geometry location such latitude and longitude, or the id of the place..

which information should i save to my database?

when people search for a country, i want the website to show every single posts in that country but i don't know how if i save the id of the place or the latitude and longitude..

i also thought of radius with the location of the country but it doesn't necessarily guarantee that this would include every single element in that country

thanks in advance!

----------- edit ----------

now i understand i am only allowed to store the unique id i get.

when searched for a city, i can get the longitude and latitude by the id and i can find places around that point with specific radius

but the problem is when i search for a country. A country also has a unique id and i don't know how to list every single place in that country

any help on that?

Comment: Please refer [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) to get some idea

Comment: I'm not sure if you are allowed to save such information to your database. It seems to be against their Terms of Service (section 10.1.3): "For example, you must not use the Content to create an independent database of "places" or other local listings information" — https://developers.google.com/maps/terms

Comment: i guess i am only allowed to store the unique id... - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21736051/storing-data-from-google-places-api)